# Vertex coloring complete minors

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, graph-minors

Say you have a graph G and with a $K_t$ minor. Let H be the smallest subgraph of G that has $K_t$ as a minor (for all $v\in V(H)$, $H\setminus v$ does not contain $K_t$ as a minor). Then we can partition H into sets $V_1, V_2, \ldots V_t$ such that $H\left[V_i\right]$ is connected for all $i\in \{1, 2, \ldots, t\}$.  If $\chi(H\left[V_i\right]) < t$ for all $i\in \{1,2,\ldots, t\}$ and the clique number of H is less than t can we say $\chi(H) \leq t$?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't any odd cycle other than $K_3$ as $H$ a counterexample already?

$\chi(H)=3$ and $\chi(H[V_i])\le2$ as any proper subgraph of $H$ is just a path.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant less than or equal to.

Comment: I am not sure what theoretical crux you are trying to address.  If one cuts up _H_ into individual vertices, then the point is moot.  On the other hand, it is obvious that building a graph by considering adding one vertex and its edges as a unit step, the graph's chromatic number cannot increase by more than 1 after a single step.